# How to use calculated result and use it as a variable in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

As the title says I am having trouble with making my calculated result into a variable that can be re use. 
This is an example of my part of the XSLT:

```
  <tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="student">
      <td><xsl:value-of select="student_id"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="sname"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="fname"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="score1"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="score2"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="score3"/></td>
      <td><xsl:variable name="total"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="score1 + score2 + score3"/></td>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="total &lt; 50">
                <td><xsl:text>N</xsl:text></td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="total &gt;= 50 and total &lt; 60">
                <td><xsl:text>C</xsl:text></td>
            </xsl:when>  
            <xsl:when test="total &gt;= 60 and total &lt; 70">
                <td><xsl:text>CR</xsl:text></td>
            </xsl:when>  
            <xsl:when test="total &gt;= 70 and total &lt; 80">
                <td><xsl:text>D</xsl:text></td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <td><xsl:text>HD</xsl:text></td>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

The result for the xsl:choose gives me all HD which is incorrect.

This is part of the XML

```
<student>
                    <student_id>16390227</student_id>
                    <sname>Battle</sname>
                    <fname>Gillian</fname>
                    <results>
                        <score1>12</score1>                     
                        <score2>13</score2>                 
                        <score3>26</score3>
                    </results>
                </student>
                <student>
                    <student_id>16280515</student_id>
                    <sname>Britt</sname>
                    <fname>Kelly</fname>
                    <results>
                        <score1>15</score1>                     
                        <score2>19</score2>                 
                        <score3>29</score3>
                    </results>
                </student>
                <student>
                    <student_id>16620827</student_id>
                    <sname>Walker</sname>
                    <fname>Kevyn</fname>
                    <results>
                        <score1>6</score1>                      
                        <score2>13</score2>                 
                        <score3>27</score3>
                    </results>
                </student>
                <student>
                    <student_id>16290814</student_id>
                    <sname>Wallace</sname>
                    <fname>Melodie</fname>
                    <results>
                        <score1>12</score1>                     
                        <score2>26</score2>                 
                        <score3>36</score3>
                    </results>
                </student>
```

This is my expected output when loaded into mozilla

```
ID sname fname   score1    score2   score3   total grades
                   12        13       26       51    C
                   15        19       29       63    CR
                   6         13       27       46    N
                   12        26       36       74    D
```

Comment: you shouldn't have = sign after &gt;

Comment: second that. `&gt;` means 'greater than'. If you want 'greater equal' use `&ge;`.

Comment: What should `"variable 1 + variable 2 + variable 3"` do? Perhaps `"$variable1 + $variable2 + $variable3" `. Seems you are *hiding* little to much here. `test="total..`  test a xml element if you try to check the variable total use `$total` but this variable is empty .

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with using `&gt=`. In fact, you cannot use anything else if you're using XSLT 1.0.

Comment: those variables are from the xml which is static so I did not think putting it in was necessary @hr_117

Comment: @MikeJoe There are no "variables" in an XML document. If you are mean *nodes* (i.e. elements or attributes), don't use the name *variable*, as it is confusing. In addition, a name cannot contain a space, so that's confusing too.

Comment: @michael.hor257k nodes, elements or attributes are names inside the <>, right ? I changed the name from variable into score to avoid confusion.

Comment: The comments from @svasa and @zx485 are completely wrong. XML has a predefined entity `&gt;`, it does not have a predefined entity `&ge;`, so the way to represent the XPath `>=` operator is as `&gt;=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The expression in:

   ```
   <xsl:when test="total &lt; 50">
   ```

   is looking at an **element** named `total`. In order to refer to
   your **variable**, use:

   ```
   <xsl:when test="$total &lt; 50">
   ```

   and so on for the rest of your tests.
2. This:

   ```
   <xsl:variable name="total"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="variable 1 + variable 2 + variable 3"/>
   ```

   does **not** populate the variable with a value. For this, you would
   have to use:

   ```
   <xsl:variable name="total">
       <xsl:value-of select="..."/>
   </xsl:variable>
   ```

   or (preferably):

   ```
   <xsl:variable name="total" select="..."/>
   ```

   Note that:

   ```
   variable 1 + variable 2 + variable 3
   ```

   is not a valid expression.
3. If you define your variable within `td` tags, its scope does not
   extend outside of those tags.
4. Note that the `xsl:choose` instruction exits at the first test that
   return true. You don't need to repeatedly test what is already known.

---

***-- edited --***

To summarize, your code should look something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="student">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="student_id"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="sname"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="fname"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="results/score1"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="results/score2"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="results/score3"/></td>
        <xsl:variable name="total" select="results/score1 + results/score2 + results/score3"/>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="$total"/></td>
        <td>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$total &lt; 50">N</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$total &lt; 60">C</xsl:when>  
                <xsl:when test="$total &lt; 70">CR</xsl:when>  
                <xsl:when test="$total &lt; 80">D</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>HD</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: How do I make the sum of the variable valid ? So that it can be used as a 'total'

Comment: @MikeJoe There is not enough information in your question to answer that. Please post a small example that shows the input and the expected output - see [mcve].

Comment: I have a few extra information and how I expect its going to show on the browser.